# Python: Grab objects with match string from Python list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
['CALSIM', '1693', '1938', '1429', '1646', '1199', '1204', '1477', '1268', '1158', '1051', '998', '1135', '2381', '2513', 'Sky19', '1627', '2124', '1859', '2504', '1690', '1784', 'Sky21', 'Sky38', '2833', 'Sky20']
```

I want to create a new list from this list that **only** includes objects with the substring `Sky` in them. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional list composition to create a new list:

```
original_list = ['CALSIM', '1693', '1938', '1429', '1646', '1199', '1204', '1477', '1268', '1158', '1051', '998', '1135', '2381', '2513', 'Sky19', '1627', '2124', '1859', '2504', '1690', '1784', 'Sky21', 'Sky38', '2833', 'Sky20']

output_list = [x for x in original_list if 'sky' in x.lower()]

>>> output_list
['Sky19', 'Sky21', 'Sky38', 'Sky20']
```

The list comp checks each value of the list, converts it to lowercase (do you care about Sky vs sky vs SKY?), and checks if the string `sky` is in that value. If yes, it's added to `output_list`.

Because we're running various string operations on the values of `original_list`, this code will error if any of your values aren't strings. You could add extra checks to catch those if that's a possibility.